# Portion of a Doubly Linked list function not working correctly

Tags: c++

in this function i have used 2 conditions , for response == 1 , pointer is returned by registration no and that function works perfectly fine, on the other hand, if response==2 , pointer is returned by the string name, in the case it takes the new input name but then programe ends suddenly,

I have added both the pointer return function and the editing function ! Please Help

```
     // edit student function , helping functions , pointer by registration and name 
     // at end    
 void LAB_PROJECT::edit_student()
 {
    int response = 0;
    string search_name;
    int search_reg = 0;

    cout << "\n \n  -- Select Search Option 1 or 2 Accordingly" << endl;
    cout << "\n       1--Registration ";
    cout << "\n       2--Student's Name" << " >>  " ;
    cin >> response;

    if (response==1)
    {
        cout << "\n \n Enter Registration No: ";
        cin >> search_reg;

        Node*temp1;

        temp1 = pointer_by_registration(search_reg);

        cin.ignore(1,'\n');
        string new_name;

        cout << "\n \n Enter New Name ";
        getline(cin,new_name,'\n');
        temp1->student_name = new_name;
        return;

    }
    else if(response==2)
    {
        cout << "\n \n Enter Student's Name , that you want to search " << endl;
        getline(cin,search_name,'\n');
        cin.ignore(1,'\n');
        Node*temp2;

        temp2 = pointer_by_name(search_name);
        string new_name;

        cout << "\n \n Enter New Name";
        getline(cin,new_name,'\n');
        cin.ignore(1,'\n');
        temp2->student_name=new_name;
        return;
    }
 }

 Node* LAB_PROJECT::pointer_by_name(string getin)
 {
       string checker;
       checker = getin;

       Node*temp1;
       temp1 = startptr;

       while(temp1 != NULL)
       {
           if (checker == temp1->student_name)
           {
               return (temp1);
           }
           temp1=temp1->nextptr;
       }
  }


 Node* LAB_PROJECT::pointer_by_registration(int reg_key)
{
int key = 0;
key = reg_key;

Node* temp1;
temp1 = startptr;

while(temp1 !=NULL)
{
    if(key == temp1->registration)
    {
        return(temp1);
    }
    temp1=temp1->nextptr;
 }
 }
```

Comment: Yes, no errors, there is some personal error probably ,, i have checked the code separatley they return pointer correctly , ,

Comment: Do you know what debugging means? debugging != compiling.

Comment: Not sure if it'll be related to your problem but both `pointer_by_` functions are missing a `return NULL` for the case where a matching Node is not found

Comment: @LuchianGrigore if i am working on Data Structures probably i know what debuggine mean !

Comment: I'm not convinced...  Anyway, why haven't you shown the part that builds your list?  Seems to me that's where the problem is likely to be.

Comment: Please help someone , Registartion works correctly the search by name gives problem when i enter new name prgrame shows send dont send error !

Comment: If you run your program in the debugger, you won't get the "Send/Don't send" dialog.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I see here at a glance is undefined behaviour in your two search functions:

```
Node* LAB_PROJECT::pointer_by_registration(int reg_key);
Node* LAB_PROJECT::pointer_by_name(string getin);
```

In both cases, you do not return a value if the search criteria is not found.  Your compiler should have given you a warning about this.  I expect you'll want to return `NULL`.

Oh, and I suppose I should add that you really need to test for `NULL` instead of assuming the functions returned a valid pointer.

Comment: I have added null if control comes out of while will that work

Comment: Why don't you *try* it and see?  You still need to test for `NULL` after you call the function.  If it returns `NULL` you are not allowed to use the pointer.  In this context it means "not found".

Comment: I have tested ,, same problem

Comment: Then edit your question and include your code that builds the list... And it wouldn't hurt to show your definition of `Node`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, code of Pointer_by_name is fine,

The problem was i entered  `cin.ignore(1,'\n');` after

```
        `cout << "\n \n Enter New Name";`
         getline(cin,new_name,'\n');`
```

Which casued the last charater of the name to flush from the stream line, it was returning a NULL Pointer but the programme freezed in its use with another function, now works Perfectly Fine .. THanks to all !